# ReactJs - Search filter with Object.keys().map - Uncaught TypeError: this.state.texts.filter is not a function at t.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter, indexof

Trying to build a simple search filter. A table of items will be filtered based on the value of an input field. Here is the relevant part of the component ... unfortunately I get an error: *Uncaught TypeError: this.state.texts.filter is not a function     at t.value*

Any idea what the issue is? Is it cause I map over keys? Thanks so much for helping out!!

```
    import React from 'react';
    import TextCardInTable from './TextCardInTable';


    const textsFileName = 'texts3.json'

    class Search extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            search: '',
            texts: [],
          };
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchData();
      }

      fetchData() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        const options = { decrypt: false }
        getFile(textsFileName, options)
          .then((file) => {
            var texts = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
            this.setState({
              texts: texts,   
            })
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false })
          })


          }

    updateSearch(event) {
       this.setState({search: event.target.value});
    }

    render () {
         let filteredTexts = this.state.texts.filter(
           (text) => {
             return text.title.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
           }
         );
         return (
           <div>
               <input type="text"
                 value={this.state.search}
                 onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
                />

                {Object.keys(filteredTexts).map(key =>
                  <TextCardInTable
                   textprops={this.state.texts[key]}
                  />
                 )}   

            </div>
          )
      }
```

Screenshot from console.log(texts):
[image]

Comment: Could you show the entire component, more specifically how your state looks?

Comment: Where do you call `this.setState()` with `texts`?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Very much appreciated. See my edit above please.

Comment: Not sure where the exact problem is but it definitely doesn't make sense that filteredTexts is presumably an array, as it's the product of a filter, but that you then call Object.keys on it. My guess is that this.state.texts is an object, so you should be calling filter on those keys.

Comment: Check the value of `texts` here: `var texts = JSON.parse(file || '[]')` -- is it something other than an array?

Comment: @pdenes JonnyRathbone Yes, it's not an array. These are objects with keys... will update above...

Comment: @Jonny-Rathbone Do you mean something like this ...

 `let filteredTexts = Object.keys(this.state.texts).filter(
      (text) => {
        return text.title.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
      }
    );`

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.texts)` will give you an array of strings with only the *keys* in `texts`, e.g. `['text1234', 'text5678']`. Looks like you're interested only in the *values*, so you could use `Object.values` instead which would give you something like `[{author: ..., title: ...}, {...}]` which you can use the filter on.

Comment: @pdenes Thanks so much! This is indeed what I was searching for. So the puzzle is solved. The issue above was that I couldn't use filter cause I haven't had an array. After transforming "texts" to an array via `Objects.values` I can use `.filter`, and things work. Do you want to add an answer? Happy to accept it. Thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, `texts` is an object, where each "text" is represented as a property, something like this:

```
{
  text123: {
    author: "a1",
    title: "t1",
    ...
  },
  text456: {
    author: "a2",
    title: "t2",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

If you want to filter these "text" items based on their `title` property, you can use `Object.values` to turn your object into an array, where you can do the filtering, e.g.:

```
Object.values(texts) // -> [{author: "a1", title: "t1"}, {author: "a2", title: "t2"},... ]
      .filter(text => text.title.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1 )
```